# How to get the current user's country code in the Spotify Apps API?

Tags: spotify

I need the country code of the current logged in Spotify user in the JavaScript API in order to not display albums that are not available in his country as required by the Spotify guidelines. I know that the user keeps anonym for an app. Does this apply for his country code as well?

Comment: To answer my question: sp = getSpotifyApi(1); models = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/models'); models.session.country

Comment: Add your answer as real answer and accept it. It really helped me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question:

```
sp = getSpotifyApi(1)
models = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/models') 
models.session.country
```